# c++ must delete a references?

Tags: c++, reference, destructor

in the following code:

```
class x
{
private:
 someRef& m_ref;

public:
 x(someRef& someRef):m_ref(someRef)
{ 
}
```

do I need to do:

```
~x()
{
  delete m_ref;
}
```

which by the way doesnt work without getting the pointer...

basically I'm asking: **Do I need to call a destructor on a reference member?**

Comment: that piece of code wont even compile

Comment: If in doubt, take a look at shared_ptr[1], it will take care of all your references and pointers for you.

  [1]http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can only delete pointers, not references, and even then you must only delete objects that you allocated using the `new` operator. And then you must be sure to delete them only once. Here is the case in which you would need to use `delete` in your destructor:

```
class x
{
private:
 someObj* m_ptr;

public:
 x():m_ptr(new someObj())
{ 
}

 ~x()
{
  delete m_ptr;
}
```

But in general it's best to avoid even this and use smart pointers instead.

Comment: just to clarify, if the parent's destructor gets called, will it also call the destructors of members that were passed by reference? I assume it won't because it wasn't initialized by the class but I might be wrong.

Comment: How is this related to reference variables?

Answer (score 19):

No.

You only need to `delete` an object if you own it. If you were passed a reference, it means that someone else owns it, thus it's unnecessary and thankfully the language prevents it.

Comment: How does the language prevent it?

Comment: @Troubadour `foo& a; delete a;` will fail (except when foo is a pointer type).

Comment: @Troubadour: as the OP mentionned, it simply does not compile.

Comment: @tstenner, @Matthieu M.: That's not the same as the "language prevents it". Just do `foo& a; delete &a`.

Comment: @Troubadour: ah but here you're deleting a pointer. The way you obtained the pointer doesn't matter to the language (that's C++), but you had to do extrawork to get it, and hopefully you realized that you were doing it wrong.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Do you agree that the language doesn't prevent it?

Comment: @Troubadour: we are not talking about the same thing :) The language prevents the deletion of a random reference, but let you call `delete` on whatever pointer. So I disagree with you on that point, but agree with you on the general point that the language does not prevent much.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: To a beginner the second sentence in your answer implies two things. Firstly that passing a reference guarantees that the ownership lies elsewhere and secondly that the language prevents you from deleting an object if all you have is a reference to it. Both of these are not true. I know exactly what you mean, I just don't think it's clear enough to a beginner.

Comment: @Troubadour: Ah! Sorry, I was not definitely not talking with a beginner mindset. I am afraid C++ is very unkind toward beginners... there are just too many pitfalls when it comes to object lifetime that the other languages don't expose any longer.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think one actually strictly speaking ever deletes even pointers. What you delete are dynamically allocated objects (or arrays of objects) that the pointer is a handle for. If the object originates from a call to **new** and it is the responsibility of this class to clean up after this object, then you call **delete**.

It is technically possible that a reference might be referring to a dynamically allocated object:

```
int main()
{
    //in principle a reference can also refer to a dynamically allocated object
    x var(*new someRef); 
}

//and if that is the intended usage:
x::~x()
{
  delete &m_ref;
}
```

However, this would be incredibly bad style. By convention, the "owning" handle of a dynamically allocated object should not be a reference.

Answer (score 2):

I want to clarify some misconceptions you seem to have that are beyond the intent of your question:

When a class's destructor is called all of it's members' destructors get called as well.

Calling `delete` is not the same as calling the destructor. `delete` explicitly calls the destructor and also calls `operator delete` at the objects location, it is a 2 part thing.

Comment: just to clarify, you mentioned `all of it's members' destructors get called as well`. Does this include members that were passed by reference in the constructor? I would assume that it won't because these objects aren't owned by the class and is probably owned the the caller of the constructor.

Comment: @Mel There's likely some standard quote applicable here that references are treated like primitives and don't have destructors. In any case, your assumption is correct.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer introduces more confusion than clarification.
Consider adding info, what is difference between calling delete and objects d-tor.
Also, a cardinal information is, that a if object holds a reference to anything bigger than plain old types (e.g. short), that should mean someone else is responsible for deleting that object - the real owner..

Answer (score 1):

For a small bit of extra clarification I want to offer the following:

```
int *pi = new int;

//int& ir = pi; // can't do
                // this a reference to the pointer but it is an error
                // because or the type difference int& vs int* and
                // static_cast won't help.  reinterpret_cast would allow
                // the assignment to take place but not help the 'delete ir'

int& ir = *pi;  // this is OK - a reference to what the pointer points to.
                // In other words, the the address of the int on the heap.

//delete ir;    // can't do, it is a reference and you can't delete non-pointers.

delete &ir;     // this works but it is still not "deleting a reference".
                // The reference 'ir' is another name for the heap-based int.
                // So, &ir is the address of that int, essentially a pointer.
                // It is a pointer that is being used by delete, not a reference.
```

Comment: "the address of the int on the heap" >.<

Comment: In fact, strictly speaking, you never "delete a pointer". You delete dynamically-allocated objects by passing pointers to them to `delete`.