# C++ Member function able to access data even it deleted the object that called it

Tags: c++, return, member, delete-operator

Here is a scenario I came across :-

```
#include <iostream>

class Agent;
class State;
class OffState;
class OnState;

class State
{
public:
    virtual void execute(Agent * agent) = 0;
    virtual ~State() {std::cout << "removing State\n";}
};

class Agent{

    State * currentState ; 
public:

    Agent();
    void update(){
        std::cout << "agent updating. will execute current State " << std::endl;
        currentState->execute(this);
    }

    void changeState(State * newState){
        delete currentState;
        currentState = newState;
    }

};

class OffState : public State
{
 public:
 ~OffState() {std::cout << "deleting OffState Object" <<std::endl;}
    void execute(Agent * agent){
        std::cout << "Nothing happens in the off State " << std::endl;
    }
};


class OnState : public State
{
static int count ; 
int id;
public:
    OnState(){
        id = count;
        count++;
    }

    ~OnState() {std::cout << "removing OnState id :- " <id<<std::endl;}

        void execute(Agent * agent){
            std::cout << "OnState executing" << std::endl;
            agent->changeState(new OffState());  
            std::cout << "executed after deleting OnState ? id:- " << id  << std::endl;
        }
};
int OnState::count = 0;

Agent::Agent():currentState(new OnState()){ 
}


main(){

    Agent smith;
    smith.update();

}
```

In this, the Agent's current state is initialised to an OnState object. This object is accessed via the update() method in Agent. This calls the OnState's execute method. Now this execute method indirectly deletes the OnState object which called it. Yet after that, control is passed back to the execute() method in the OnState object. What's more it is able to print the value of "id" . Shouldn't the memory pointed be deleted because of the delete currentState .

Or is this the case where in some cases, the system may crash and in some cases, the memory contents wouldn't be immediately filled up by the operating system.

I thought that the function definition isn't stored in memory specific to instances as such, but this does not explain how the "id" value is still accessible.

The output of the code was :-

```
agent updating. will execute current State 
OnState executing
removing OnState id :- 0
removing State
```

executed after deleting OnState ? id:- 0

Regards.

Comment: `Agent` is not defined anywhere. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: saw it to late :)

Comment: sorry added it now. (paste had gone wrong)

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: ok, and what if the function did not make use of id at all. what if after changeState() , all there was in that method was just a return statement. Would that be a safe function ? (it is clearly unsafe right now as it's printing "id")

Comment: That's fine. You are essentially doing `delete this;`, which is legal as long as the member function doesn't access `this` thereafter.

Comment: Ok, this question is resolved. How should i close it. Without the need of an answer. Can you frame your response as an answer ? Or should we keep it open as it is.

Comment: @ameyask86 Once someone gives the answer you can select that as the right answer or you can make a comprehensive answer and post it yourself. There is no "close" as such in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete pointers, not references.
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078998/c-must-delete-a-references) . This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 *"why still can access deleted instance's virtual functions and member variable"*

Function call use instance when calling virtual functions and member variables, in following scenario: After your deletion, if another allocation incidentally allocated in your released block, and change the virtual function pointer's values in your deleted instance, which would trigger exception when you called.

Memory deletion only result in heap block returned back to free list of heap by heap management.(both for glibc and windows heap). Heap never return virtual pages back to virtual memeory manager, which means deleted memory in heap you can access and when only read in valid range wouldn't trigger any exception.

Question 2 *"I thought that the function definition isn't stored in memory specific to instances as such, but this does not explain how the "id" value is still accessible."*

Function definition in your executable file is in code segment(for dll would shared between processes and in some senrior would trigger COW), Newed variables are allocated in heap. As explained, memory can be accessed, so before the heap block is taken by other allocation, you still can access your previous value(As i know both windows heap and glic wouldn't refill or reset the deletion block's value because of performance).

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a member of a deleted object results in **undefined behavior**.

Reading a deleted object's member value will usually return whatever is present at that address. Bear in mind that a new object can be allocated at that address in the meantime, so you can get a different value from the old member value.

You're using the `new` operator to allocate the `OnState` object, so it will be allocated on the heap. A member variable is part of the object stored in heap memory and you have a pointer to it. Even if you deleted the object, you can still read its members through the pointer.

The read access should never throw an exception as long as virtual memory pages are not reclaimed (anyway, it's a bad idea to rely on this assumption).